# What is the best way to remove/break carbon carbon bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am working on synthesis homework and I can not figure out how to remove a carbon substituent from a cyclohexane.

[image]

What is the best way to remove the three carbons and exchange them for a ketone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible pathway is as follows:

[image: pathway]

At high temperatures, formation of the more substituted alkene will be favored. Catalytic amounts of base provide a kinetic pathway for this rearrangement. $\ce{OsO4}$ creates a vicinal diol, while $\ce{NaIO4}$ cleaves the $\ce{C-C}$ bond and oxidizes the alcohols to carbonyls. Additionally, $\ce{NaIO4}$ oxidizes $\ce{(HO)2OsO2}$ back to $\ce{OsO4}$, allowing the reaction cycle to continue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt know you could use base+water to rearragne a double bond like that. Very helpful

Comment: Quick question, what program are you using to draw out the compounds?

Comment: @unrnick ChemDraw. If you are at an uni, you should be able to get it for free

Comment: Worth noting that OsO4 is a nasty (and expensive) chemical, which leads to the main benefit of using NaIO4 as a co-oxidant: you get to use OsO4 in catalytic quantities.

Comment: @orthocresol I wouldn’t be sure periodate is a co-catalyst here. From what I learnt, $\ce{OsO4}$ generates the diol which is periodate-cleaved to two carbonyl groups.

Comment: @Jan that's what's said in the answer, at least. I looked it up: [JOC 1956, 21, 478](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo01110a606) "Catalytic amounts of osmium tetroxide are sufficient because periodate oxidises osmium in its lower valence forms to the tetroxide, thus regenerating the hydroxylating agent."

Comment: @orthocresol Oh yeah, I should have read better =D. Of couse, you can use pretty much *any* co-catalyst, but using periodate has the benefit of co-performing the cleavage.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a variation of *ringo*'s method:

1. Treat the alkene with $\ce{OsO4}$/$\ce{NaIO4}$ to obtain a cyclohexyl methyl ketone
2. Convert the ketone to cyclohexyl acetate by using a peracid (MCPBA).
3. Cleave the ester
4. Oxidize the cyclohexanol to cyclohexanone with a mild oxidant

Answer (score 4):

I can offer another two-step synthesis:

1. isomerise the double bond as ringo mentioned.
2. Criegee reaction ($\ce{O3}$) followed by workup with $\ce{PPh3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Ozonolysis followed by reduction, elimination of water next ozonolysis (repeat till you have cyclohexanone) looks like the best solution for me.